# Can I intercept an Activity in between instantiation onCreate using ActivityScenario?

Tags: android, android-testing

In my unit tests I need to work on an instance of an Activity object before `onCreate` has
been run. Any way to do that with the `ActivityScenario`/`ActivityScenarioRule` helper functions?

If I add an `ActivityScenarioRule`, the activity is both constructed and created before I can access it. The same with `ActivityScenario.launch`

Comment: found similar (but not equal) question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388847/how-to-get-the-activity-reference-before-its-oncreate-gets-called-during-testing